# Memory consumption jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have several build jobs running on jenkins and I am installed a plugin "JavaMelody" for monitor memory consumptions. The allocated heap size is 8GB and currrently the java memory used is 2.5 GB.

Now I access the machine where the jenkins master is running, open task manager, identify the jenkins  instance for the team and see that java.exe is consuming is more than 8GB memory.

I am confused here. 2.5 GB OR 8GB is used for Java memory. Some explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

That is the difference between used memory in the java heap and used memory allocated for the heap by the java process (the jvm).

In fact, the jvm has reserved 8GB of memory for the heap but internally it is currently using only 2.5GB inside the heap. And used memory in the heap is varying a lot every second between new objects in the heap and the Garbage Collector cleaning up.

So 2.5GB of currently used memory in a 8GB heap is quite normal.

By the way, the memory used by the java process is more than 8GB because the java process also uses non-heap memory, in addition to the memory you have allocated for the heap. But that was not the question.